# Python Audio Sampler

Tags: python, audio, sampling

I have a rather unique problem it seems, after trawling through google for quite some time. I'm in the process of building an audio sampler with the sparkfun monome keypad, an arduino and a raspberry pi. The concept is use the arduino to listen for a keypress, send a character identifying the key over serial to the raspberry pi, and have a python script listening to the serial port ready to play the sample on keypress. I have gotten to the point where I can play an audio sample on keypress, yet the sample only plays on keypresses which align with the sample: for example, I can have a keypress twice every 1 second, yet still have the sample play only once a second. I actually want a setup that allows me to play samples as quickly as the presses register (which I have verified do not correspond to the playing of the sample, through monitoring the TX led as well as the serial port). My script is very simple as of yet, and only has two sounds configured to play for testing purposes:

```
import serial
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init(22050, -16, 1, 1024)

sndA = pygame.mixer.Sound('testSound1.wav')
sndB = pygame.mixer.Sound('testSound2.wav')

soundChannelA = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
soundChannelB = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMC0', 9600)

while True:
    try:
        if '0' in ser.readline():
            soundChannelA.play(sndA)
        if '1' in ser.readline():
            soundChannelB.play(sndB)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want, e.g., testsound1.wav to restart everytime the user presses the 0 key. According to the documentation for [pygame.mixer.Channel](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel):

> If the Channel is currently playing any other Sound it will be
>   stopped.

This makes me wonder if the pygame code checks if you are asking it to play to *same* sound on the channel and ignores the request.

Perhaps the solution is as simple as calling the Channel object's stop() method before calling the play() method:

```
if '0' in ser.readline():
    soundChannelA.stop()
    soundChannelA.play(sndA)
if '1' in ser.readline():
    soundChannelB.stop()
    soundChannelB.play(sndB)
```

Comment: This is something I completely didn't think of... I'll give it a try, and keep you posted, but this might be answer I'm looking for

Comment: Did you find out if this is the solution and if so, could you mark the answer?